# Writing a backslash in the \texttt environment

Tags: characters, typewriter

How do you go about writing a backslash inside `\texttt`? The `$\backslash$` trick makes the font inconsistent. The reason I am asking is that I am writing some introductory computer science material and need to talk about different escape characters in `printf` and other functions. The verbatim environment adds new lines while I would like my finished product to be strictly inline.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about using `\verb` instead of `\texttt`?

```
The first exercise uses \verb$printf("Hello world!\n");$.
```

You can use (almost) any character you like instead of `$`.

Better still, if you're typesetting a lot of code, use the `listings` package that provides a `\lstinline` macro, equivalent to `\verb` but with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Great! Didn't know that `verbatim` had an inline shortcut. That is really handy!

Comment: There is also `\texttt{printf("Hello world!\string\n");}`.

Comment: Warning: ```\verb``` does not work inside the argument of another command!

Answer (score 39):

You can use `\textbackslash` rather than `$\backslash$` to keep the current font. With `$..$` you change to math font.

```
\texttt{This is a backslash: \textbackslash.}
```

Comment: I actually noticed the the font changes from monospace to normal text when using pdftex at least. It was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: With pdf(la)tex the symbol is not available for the standard typewriter font. I tested with lualatex and the fontspec package:

   \documentclass{memoir}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \begin{document}
   \noindent
   \textbackslash\ \ldots the backslash in roman font.\   \texttt{\textbackslash\ \ldots the backslash in typewriter font.}
   \end{document}

Comment: This is good to know. I will start fiddling with other tex implementations. Also thank you for catching the pdf(la)tex issue! I somehow always forget that even when talking about it... which of course is bad seeing that it refers to something completely different.

Comment: Kevin, could you explain what does "the symbol is not available for the standard typewriter font" actually mean? `\verb` and `\typettt` seems to use the same font, so it's not clear to me how the monospaced backslash can exist for `\verb` and not exist for `\typettt`.

Comment: If you use T1 encoding this will use the expected font, it only uses the math font if the legacy OT1 encoding is used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as per your suggestion, I added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, and it worked like a charm! Maybe you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 24):

or you can try: `` \texttt{\char`\\} ``
(for me it looks better than `\texttt{\textbackslash}`)

Comment: @Downvoter Please do not downvote a new user before you haven't commented and waited for a response. Now that your vote has been made please leave a comment why you did so and a proposal on how to improve the answer.

Comment: @ChrisPer Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: +1 because this is a method applicable for any ASCII character (more or less special in TeX) and usable in macro parameters (where `\verb` cannot be used). For example ``\texttt{\char`\{}``, ``\texttt{\char`\^}`` etc.

Answer (score 6):

`\textbackslash{}` looks the best choice.
It may be used alone as well as in `\texttt{'\textbackslash{}xAA'}` (to get `'\xAA'`) and alikes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\symbol{92}`. The same trick works for $, & and other special characters.

Comment: ``\symbol{`\\}`` is easier (no lookup in ASCII table).