# Writing a typewriter-text backslash character in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, verbatim

I'm having trouble trying to write a typewriter-text backslash in a footnote.

There are two solutions for writing a typewriter-text backslash provided at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131635/writing-a-backslash-in-the-texttt-environment):

1. Use `\textbackslash`.
2. Use `\verb`, an inline version of the `verbatim` environment.  (The `verbatim` environment causes unwanted newlines.)

Both of these solutions have (different!) problems in my particular case.

1. As indicated in [the comments below this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131669/7035), `pdflatex` doesn't use the correct font for `\textbackslash` in `\texttt`.  There seems to be some confusion about why this is occurring, but this is far beyond my level of expertise.
2. `\verb` can't be used in the argument to a command.  Unfortunately, and somewhat hilariously, [the only workaround I've been able to find](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349974/verb-in-theorem-environment-option) suggests using a custom command to go back to using `\texttt`!  (I do not believe the solution to [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108841/macro-verb-inside-tabu-environment) is relevant, but I'm not sure.)

Are there any ways to escape (possibly literally) this dilemma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only an issue  with `\textbackslash` if you use the legacy OT1 encoding which you should normally avoid for many reasons.  With the "new" (1990) T1 encoding you get the expected result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\texttt{\textbackslash abc}\footnote{\texttt{\textbackslash abc}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  (I see that you also left a comment below the relevant answer in the linked question - thanks for doing that too!)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the `cprotect` package which allows using `\verb` inside of footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cprotect}

\begin{document}
\cprotect\footnote{\verb!\!}
\end{document}
```